# External Display issue with P50 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, xorg, multiple-monitors, xrandr

I own a Lenovo ThinkPad P50 and I'm trying to get working an external monitor connected via DVI. I have tried with HDMI also, but I encountered the same issue.
Let's say I have a dock station like the one in the link (https://support.lenovo.com/ie/en/documents/acc100247), even though I have the following problem when not using it too.
So I think it's not a problem due to the dock station neither to the used port.

My system is:

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04.1
- Kernel: 4.4.0-34
- Bios: CMS enabled and Discrete graphic
- DE: Unity & lightdm
- Nvidia driver: 361

I'm able to connect an external monitor (LT2452p - res: 1920x1200), and using the Display application I can enable it and position it to the right/left of the laptop's primary display. However I'd like to position the two monitors one above the other one, vertically. If I try so, the result is horrible and not manageable. The screenshot below should help to understand the problem.

I have also tried via command line, using **xrandr**, but I had no luck, too.

`xrandr -q` outupt:

```
br1@br1-thinkpad-p50:~$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.99    59.94    50.00    60.05    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1366x768      59.79  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-6 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

The command I have used was:

```
xrandr --output DP-4 --auto --primary --output DP-1 --above DP-4
```

The `nvidia-settings` utility does not help too.
Finally sometimes it happens that connecting the external monitor after the laptop booted, both monitors start to blink (like turning on/off) without stopping.

Does anyone have any tip/suggestion in order to fix that? Or at least, where I can start for digging from?

Issue screenshot - result after monitors are positioned one above the other:
[image]

Comment: What was the `xrandr` command you ran, and what are the resolutions of the screens?

Comment: @JacobVlijm I have update my question with info you asked.

Comment: Thanks! could you see if the command `xrandr --output DP-1 --pos 0x0 --output DP-4 --pos 1080x0` works? screens need to be arranged from left to right, from top to bottom for the command to work.

Comment: Is that wrong? Cause they are overlapped right now. edit: I went with `xrandr --output DP-1 --pos 0x0 --output DP-4 --pos 1920x0` and the external monitor is not on the left of the primary. I'd like to have it on top (or bottom) of the primary.

Comment: Ah shoot, sorry, mixed x and y. should be `xrandr --output DP-1 --pos 0x0 --output DP-4 --pos 0x1080`

Comment: Yeah, I tried, however it's still the same. Xrandr does what we say, but the result is not what we expect. I got the same result of the screenshot.

Comment: Silly question, but what happens if you arrange the other screen to be on top? The width obviously is set incorrectly.

Comment: Well, it's not the width that's set wrongly, but the height. It's like it's half of what it should be. Anyway I have tried both top and bottom of the primary laptop and got same result :/


Aside note: I have installed GNOME3 as DE and with it, monitor positioning works perfectly. So, can I suspect it's a lightdm bug? 
By the way, I feel really comfortable with lightdm right now and I wish I dont have to replace it with Gnome.